# Jinja2/Flask makes my table tags disappear?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, flask-security

I'm trying to modify [Flask-Security's `_macros.html`](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/templates/security/_macros.html) to nicely align everything. I replaced the `p` tags with `tr` and wrapped `{{ field.label }}` and `{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}` both between `td` tags. For some reason those tags totally vanish from the output *poof*, like they've never been there. Using some nonsense like `trrrrr` and `tdddd` outputs just fine, so I know I'm editing the right file.

What's going on? Why does jinja2 hate my tables?

I also tried about wrapping the macro call in the template between `<td></td>` and then every supposedly wrapping tag just appear **after** all the macro calls without any content in between (but above).

I tried googling my vanishing tags but couldn't find anything.

```
{% macro render_field_with_errors(field) %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ field.label }}</td> <td>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}</td>
    {% if field.errors %}
      <ul>
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </tr>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <td>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}</td>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: but you didn't supply the code so no one can potentially see the error you made in the edits...

Comment: @Attack68 I pasted the template in the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the tr tags in a parent table tag fixed the issue for me